# ¿Cómo usar la tablas de la base de datos pública de Google en BigQuery?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, google-bigquery

Estoy haciendo un curso de análisis de datos y en varios ejercicios toca usar datos de la base de datos Pública de BigQuery, la cual tiene tablas con las que e puede trabajar las funciones, se crear los espacios de trabajo y buscar las tablas, pero como no coinciden las versiones de los videos con la nueva es difícil, no sé como subirla para tratar de hacer los ejercicios de SQL. Por favor me serviría una asesoría

Busque la tabla de la base de datos Pública de BigQuery y encuentro la tabla con la cual trabajar, pero no sé como subirla al espacio de trabajo no encuentro algún botón para subirla y trabajar el SQL

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Seria bueno que especificaras que tecnología en concreto buscas usar, que es lo que has hecho si puedes con screenshots para ver cual es el error que tienes. Se busca resolver problemas concretos.